# Using NSStringFromSelector to send method over a network

Tags: objective-c, networking

I'm currently making a client-client approach on some simulation with objective-c with two computers (mac1 and mac2).

I have a class Client, and every computer has a instance of the "Client" on it (client1,client2). I expect that both clients will be synchronized: they will both be equal apart from memory locations.

When a user presses a key on mac1, I want both client1 and client2 to receive a given method from class Client (so that they are synchronized, i.e. they are the same apart from it's memory location on each mac).

To this approach, my current idea is to make 2 methods:

```
- (void) sendSelector:(Client*)toClient,...;
- (void) receiveSelector:(Client*)fromClient,...;
```

sendSelector: uses NSStringFromSelector() to transform the method to a NSString, and send it over the network (let's not worry about sending strings over net now).

On the other hand, receiveSelector: uses NSSelectorFromString() to transform a NSString back to a selector.

My first question/issue is: to what extent is this approach "standard" on networking with objective-c?

My second question:

And the method's arguments? Is there any way of "packing" a given class instance and send it over the network? I understand the pointer's problem when packing, but every instance on my program as an unique identity, so that should be no problem since both clients will know how to retrieve the object from its identity.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me address your second question first:

> And the method's arguments? Is there any way of "packing" a given
>   class instance and send it over the network?

Many Cocoa classes implement/adopt the NSCoding @protocol.  This means they support some default implementation for serializing to a byte stream, which you could then send over the network. You would be well advised to use the NSCoding approach unless it's fundamentally not suited to your needs for some reason. (i.e. use the highest level of abstraction that gets the job done)

Now for the more philosophical side of your first question; I'll rephrase your question as "is it a good approach to use serialized method invocations as a means of communication between two clients over a network?"

First, you should know that Objective-C has a not-often-used-any-more, but reasonably complete, implementation for handling remote invocations between machines with a high level of abstraction. It was called Distributed Objects. Apple appears to be shoving it under the rug to some degree (with good reason -- keep reading), but I was able to find an old cached copy of the [Distributed Objects Programming Topics](http://pooh.poly.asu.edu/Cst502/Resources/ObjectiveC/AppleDistrObjects.pdf) guide. You may find it informative.  AFAIK, all the underpinnings of Distributed Objects still ship in the Objective-C runtime/frameworks, so if you wanted to use it, if only to prototype, you probably could.

I can't speculate as to the exact reasons that you can't seem to find this document on developer.apple.com these days, but I think it's fair to say that, in general, you don't want to be using a remote invocation approach like this in production, or over insecure network channels (for instance: over the Internet.) It's a huge potential attack vector. Just think of it: If I can modify, or spoof, your network messages, I can induce your client application to call arbitrary selectors with arbitrary arguments. It's not hard to see how this could go **very** wrong.

At a high level, let me recommend coming up with some sort of protocol for your application, with some arbitrary wire format (another person mentioned JSON -- It's got a lot of support these days -- but using NSCoding will probably bootstrap you the quickest), and when your client receives such a message, it should read the message *as data* and make a decision about what action to take, without actually deriving at runtime what is, in effect, *code* from the message itself.

From a "getting things done" perspective, I like to share a maxim I learned a while ago: "Make it work; Make it work right; Make it work fast. In that order."

For prototyping, maybe you don't care about security.  Maybe when you're just trying to "make it work" you use Distributed Objects, or maybe you roll your own remote invocation protocol, as it appears you've been thinking of doing. Just remember: you really need to "make it work right" *before* releasing it into the wild, or those decisions you made for prototyping expedience could cost you dearly. The best approach here will be to create a class or group of classes that abstracts away the network protocol and wire format from the rest of your code, so you can swap out networking implementations later without having to touch *all* your code.

One more suggestion: I read in your initial question a desire to 'keep an object (or perhaps an object graph) in sync across multiple clients.' This is a complex topic, but you may wish to employ a "Command Pattern" (see the Gang of Four book, or any number of other treatments in the wild.) Taking such an approach may also inherently bring structure to your networking protocol. In other words, once you've broken down all your model mutation operations into "commands" maybe your protocol is as simple as serializing those commands using NSCoding and shipping them over the wire to the other client and executing them again there.

Hopefully this helps, or at least gives you some starting points and things to consider.

Answer (score 0):

These days it would seem that the most standard way is to package everything up on JSON.